# vb.net word automation - bookmarks

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I am preparing to make mechanism to fill out word template. I want to fill out it by data from my program. I heard about word bookmarks that I could create and then from program put the data to it. Unfortunately I heard also that when I want to put same value in different places in word I need to prepare separated new bookmarks for it. For instance I want surname to be in 3 different places in word then i cannot use one bookmark for it. Is it true? If so is there any other way to do it?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Have you tried [gimmethecodez.com?](http://www.gimmethecodez.com)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can fill out bookmarks from your program. Be aware of the two different types of bookmarks which are called open or closed (one is empty, the other contains text and you can replace parts of the text or the whole text).
Yes, you can use a bookmark name only once. But you can manipulate the bookmarks in your program when you use bookmarks like bookmark_1 and bookmark_2, so you can replace the same content on different places. Helpful is the object model (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff841749%28v=office.14%29.aspx)